# How to fix 'type is not assignable to any' when addressing a member

Tags: typescript

I have a code like this:

```js
interface IFoo {
  bar: string;
  baz: number;
}

function f(foo: IFoo, name: 'bar' | 'baz', val: any) {
  foo[name] = val;   // <<< error: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}
```

If I change the type of "baz" to be also "string" then the error is gone:

```js
interface IFoo {
  bar: string;
  baz: string;
}

function f(foo: IFoo, name: 'bar' | 'baz', val: any) {
  foo[name] = val;   // fine
}
```

Why is this happening, and would it be possible to fix this?
I'm looking for a solution that is better than replacing `name: 'bar' | 'baz'` with `name: string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure, that the `val` has the correct type that corresponds to the provided `name`.

[Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyyARnFAFzIDOYUoA5gNyElwBelIArgLbHTMAvvnwwuIBGGCYQyGAB4A0sggAPSCAAmVZAGsIAT0ww0WTAD4AFDGyUM2ADTIQcHhEqKnANzgAbO2YA2ooAugCUeCw2mIEubiHIALzIPr6MRMgA9JnI8nkqUFCYFMgAKgYADigA5HAgBtXIwDogmGDIcFRUwPQuxL4oYDhglTUgEF7Q1QB0%20ML4CDI0cram2EmRGawl1dUOLESkHMgADHMiMNaOyNWkUHs3cMQI1WGiV5hOt%20wPAIxvixAVEwA2mvkw9A%20YUYQA)

```js
interface IFoo {
  bar: string;
  baz: number;
}

function f<K extends keyof IFoo>(foo: IFoo, name: K, val: IFoo[K]) {
  foo[name] = val;
}

const foo: IFoo = {
    bar: '',
    baz: 0
}

f(foo, 'bar', 'abc')
f(foo, 'baz', 1)
console.log(foo);
```

or more general

```js
function f<T, K extends keyof T>(foo: T, name: K, val: T[K]) {
  foo[name] = val;
}
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyyARnFAFzIDOYUoA5gNyElwBelIArgLbHTMAvvnwwuIBGGCYQyGAB4AKgBpkAaWQQAHpBAATKsgDWEAJ6YYyRQD4AFDGyUVyEHB4RKa1QDc4AGycAbTUAXQBKPBYHTEDXdxDkAF5kXz8hEQQZGjlHNCwcZIIiIlIKZABycuUWEvZKAAZ8YVF7bFVy0qqKuGIEcrCW6PbSNi6ARgHMkCpMPwgAOj9MelbMMMYgA)